# Jekyll Serve - Content Duplication

Tags: duplicates, jekyll, blogs, posts

I recently was able to get Jekyll serve --watch to work. Now I see that that there are duplicates of most of my blog posts. I've tried to moving posts around, deleting them from the _site folder, checking for duplicates in the website. But nothing has been working. Is this typical of Jekyll serve? If I build, will the duplicates also be published?

[image: Duplicate image]

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code...

Comment: Is it happening for all your posts or is a random behaviour? Maybe the problem is in your layout code...

Comment: Deleting the _site folder helped. There's about 3 posts that still get copied, because if I don't keep them in 2 folders, it causes errors and the site won't serve. Not sure why yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a tipical behaviour, posts should appear once.

Also `watch` is turned on by default when serving the site locally with jekyll serve.

Remove the `_site` folder and serve the website again.